# Fps Question on Threads

Tags: multithreading, frame-rate

In a standard frames per second type game, where the developer can set the number of frames per second, is there one thread for drawing to the screen and movement by environmental forces such as gravity, or are there separate threads: maybe one thread for drawing to the screen, and another for moving objects based on gravitational forces. Basically I'm trying to understand FPS. How does it work?

Comment: In windows only one thread can modify the UI. So anything else that happens simultaneously is happening on another thread or other process. This is true of any type of app. Not really an answer to the larger question about FPS

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for it.

The modern state-of-the-art games like Killzone, Half-Life, etc. are multi-threaded and have different threads for networking, physics, rendering, where all threads have to be 
synchronized. 
Which also could be a bottleneck, when for example all task are done but not the physics.
Then the other threads would have to wait for the

But you could also run all in a single thread run one after another task.